# How to separate test account purchase from real purchase in android in app billing?

Tags: android, testing, account

I have implemented In App Purchase in my android app for purchasing items using the help and sample app provided on Google developer site.

I have set the test account to check the transactions on goggle wallet account.

Can any one tells me how to identify test account purchase vs real purchase, beacuse i want to show only real purchase request and data in our customized analytic.

There is a way to identify the sandbox purchase vs real purchase in IOS, so is there any way or receipt data change so that i can separate out the test purchase and real one.

Answer (score 1):

Test purchases have "Test:" prefixed in their description within the developer console.

Use this to filter your data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. but how can i indetify from the purchase receipt or any other way that it is a test account purchase, so that on server side i can seperate out the test purchase or real purchase..... say... i want to add all the test account purchases in one database table and real purchase in other... thank you very much again....

Comment: Hi Sir, I Highly appreciate your answer, but sir, above mentioned filter can be applied on the wallet account, what i need is, "when i send test purchase data and real purchase data to my server through webservice call, then at server end, how i will come to know that the purchase request is test or real, so that i can further transfer the request to test database or real purchase database(database is used on my server for storing purchase info and other stuffs!!!).".... thank you very much again for quick reply....

Comment: That is not what you asked. You said "but how can i indetify from the purchase receipt OR ANY OTHER WAY that it is a test account purchase". At no point did you mention using your web service. You should amend your question so that you are asking for the information you require.

Comment: I am extreamly sorry for the same and i apologies for giving improper information. Can you please guide me how do i seperate test purchase request or real purchase request on server side. one more question, are both purchase receipts(test account and real purchase) are exactly same?